# python built in server not loading css

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, static-files

when i runserver the django admin is missing css.The web console says that style sheet  was not loaded because its MIME type,"application/x-css", is not "text/css". 
This is my settings.py file

## Django settings for mysite project.

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': 'C:/djangorevision/mysite/sqlite3.db',                       database 
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                   
        'PORT': '',                     
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True


USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = ''


STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/djangorevision/mysite/static'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
 #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '*4#u_xz-+7cp-x-)w(o*sr1&amp;1$^fa409_d@7!&amp;z%_(93u=@s=o'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  )

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polls'
```

)

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,`enter code here`
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. And it seems you are right about Dreamweaver. Adding above mentioned strings into settings.py didn't helped me.

I have run search for `.css` at regedit and changed most suspicious registry keys/records which

1. could be related to treating .css files as application/x-css type
2. could be related to associating .css file extension to opening with applications, especially Dreamweaver.

It took me two iterations and I can not say for sure which one was the right shot as it might needed some time to update some cache, etc.

Though I changed it at two locations:

1. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.css
2. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css

I renamed (by adding leading '--' so that it could be recovered if necessary) keys/records related to `.css` files association with all applications (including Dreamweaver, Notepad, etc.) and stating `.css` files as application/x-css type.

After that the issue was resolved and Django CSS styles were correctly applied as it was expected.

Comment: Could you kindly state clearly what you renamed. I ran regedit and could not get clearly what i was to rename in those hierarchies

Comment: In the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.css` find following record `Name: Content Type; Type: REG_SZ; Value: application/x-css`, where `Name`, `Type` and `Value` are column headers on the right side of the regedit window.

Click at `Content Type`. Call context menu (right button click) and select "Rename". Type `--` before `Content Type` so that the new Name will say `--Content Type`.

Repeat the same steps for another record with a `text/css` in the `Value` column.

Go to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css`.

You will find the same two records. Repeat the same steps.

Comment: it worked great... I also think Dreamweaver had a hand on it because in another machine without Dreamweaver installed it works fine

Answer (score 7):

A little late answer but this needs to be put here for completeness.

I also got this strange error on one development system (I didn't get it on other development systems for the same project). Maybe it is related to the fact that Dreamweaver (which can open css files) was installed on this system?

In any case, to resolve the issue I added the following in my settings.py:

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
```

This will add (and replace if already exists) the correct mimetype for css in your mimetypes list.

In case you don't want to put it in your settings.py, add it to the `__init__.py` file of yout settings package.

Comment: i included the above but i still got the error. i have dreamweaver installed in my system

Comment: Where did you included it ? Are youy sure that it is executed ? Try adding a print statement after ``mimetypes.add_type`` to be sure that it runs.

Comment: i included it in my settings.py, i also added the print statement and it executed.

Comment: Hmm... it works in my case, i really don't know what is the problem :|

Comment: the above answer solved the problem but it was great that you introduced the issue on Dreamweaver had a hand on it

Answer (score -1):

Setting DEBUG in your setting file fix this:

```py
DEBUG = True
```