# Why css for admin url in python-django project is not loading?

Tags: python, css, django, static, admin

I am new to python & django. I have learnt basic of both and made a simple project called **PythonDjangoDemo**. I have visited admin urls during development. But I am unable to load css for admin url in python-django project. At first lets look at project structure. I have -

```
PythonDjangoDemo
  |--- PythonDjangoDemo
  |      |--- __init__.py
  |      |--- settings.py
  |      |--- urls.py
  |      |--- wsgi.py
  |--- static_cdn
  |      |--- admin
  |      |      |--- css
  |      |      |      |---base.css
  |      |      |      |---login.css
  |      |      |--- fonts
  |      |      |--- img
  |      |      |--- js
  |--- media_cdn
  |--- templates
  |--- manage.py
  |--- db.sqlite3
```

Let's have a look at settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

... ... ...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

I have put all my css for admin urls at "static_cdn/admin/css". When I try to access "127.0.0.1:800/admin"  I do not get any error(s). Here is the console output -

```
[30/Apr/2017 16:04:58] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[30/Apr/2017 16:04:59] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1650
[30/Apr/2017 16:04:59] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16066
[30/Apr/2017 16:04:59] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1203
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[30/Apr/2017 16:04:59] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2329
```

Could you please explain

- What is going on wrong compared to the console response (that is no error)?
- And what is the meaning of **STATIC_URL** and **STATIC_ROOT**?

Comment: This is with ``DEBUG = True`` or ``False``?

Comment: Also did you run ``collectstatic``?

Comment: `DEBUG = True` and I also run `collectstatic` @Grimmy

Comment: @Grimmy , take a look -- I put css files at `/static_cdn/admin/css/base.css`. But console output is --  `/static/admin/css/base.css`. Is it `static` or `static_cdn`?

Comment: @Grimmy , There is no error detected in the browsers [checked in chrome & firefox] also. But they are showing --- `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css: "http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css".` **and** `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css: "http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/login.css".`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I got the solution to the problem. Though everything is OK but the browser's console shows -

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css: "http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css". 
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css: "http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/login.css".
```

> The problem was discussed at [python built in server not loading css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839278/python-built-in-server-not-loading-css).
>
> I got the solution at [CSS not loading wrong MIME type Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557129/css-not-loading-wrong-mime-type-django).

Answer (score 0):

your css is loading fine as you can see there is no error.

check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) for details.

Also your media folder should be at the same level as the static folder.

Answer (score 0):

you should put static_cdn folder in parallel to media_cdn folder.

Then clear the cache and load  admin page.

Comment: Those (static_cdn & media_cdn) are in parallel.  @Rahul Gupta

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static-only"),
```

I put my static files as above and created it in my Django base directory.
Afterwards I ran `django manage.py collectstatic`.
Then ran `django manage.py runserver` but it still didn't work.
Until I cleared my BROWSER CACHE.

Comment: import and add also the mimetypes as indicated