# Cannot load webUI correctly

Tags: locust

I could get the page on localhost:8089 but not the style.css .These are the results from firefox and chrome:

Firefox:

```
GET http://localhost:8089/static/style.css?v=1.0   [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 17ms]
The stylesheet http://localhost:8089/static/style.css?v=1.0 was not loaded because its MIME type, “application/x-css”, is not “text/css”.
```

Chrome:

```
localhost/:5 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css: "http://localhost:8089/static/style.css?v=1.0".
```

How to make the web normal? pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible you are encountering the same problem mentioned here?

https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-start-but-stylesheets-not-displayed/3250/11

Specifically check your registry (https://gogs.io/docs/intro/troubleshooting#windows):

- Error: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-css
- Causes: wrong value in the Windows registry
- Solution: Find .css in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in registry and change its Content Type to text/css.

Comment: Or maybe this is something that should be fixed in locust. @heyman what do you think? Could/should we do something along the lines of the second answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839278/python-built-in-server-not-loading-css

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works after I changed registry setting and cleared browsers' cache @Cyberwiz.