# Refused to apply style because its MIME type (text/html) is not supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: python, html, css, django, css-selectors

I am working on a django project and I have created index.html file in template folder. Style.css is not working meaning style is not applying on any of the html files and is showing "Refused to apply style because its MIME type(text/html) is not supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I have tried working with style.css in external folder and also the common folder as well but the html file remained unchanged. Style can't be applied on any of the html attribute.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35557129/2518285) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22839278/2518285) has been asked before. Please do a search before asking a new question. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35557243/2518285) help? Or what about [this thread](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/mime-type-text-html-is-not-supported-as-css/18795/3)?